# Given `false_v<T> = false`, `static_assert(false_v<T>)` compiles inside `if constexpr (false)`. Is this legal?

Tags: c++, static-assert, if-constexpr

Consider this code that static asserts false inside an `if constexpr (false)` statement.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct False {
    static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template<typename T>
struct Foo {
    void foo() {
        if constexpr (false) {
            static_assert(False<T>::value);
        }
        std::cout
            << "Static assert expression was: "
            << False<T>::value
            << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo<int> foo;
    foo.foo();
}
```

On both GCC 12.2 and LLVM 15.0.0, this code compiles and prints:

> Static assert expression was: 0

With even minor changes, this code does not compile.  Changing `static_assert(False<T>::value);` to `static_assert(False<int>::value);` or removing the `if constexpr (false)` check or changing it to `if constexpr (true)`, I get "static assertion failed" as expected.

Is my above code legal?  My understanding was that `static_assert(...evaluates to false)` is ill-formed, but the code compiles.

Comment: IIRC - `if constexpr (false)` inside a template is allowed to contain ill-formed code.

Comment: Found it  _"...The discarded statement can odr-use a variable that is not defined:..."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if and _"...Outside a template, a discarded statement is fully checked. if constexpr is not a substitute for the #if preprocessing directive:..."_ and a few more lines of explanation and examples

Comment: @DrewDormann I think you're right, I assume that when the template is instantiated the `false` branches of any `if constexpr` statements are discarded *before* static_asserts are checked.  (In this code, the template itself is not invalid because some later code could in principle override `FalseT` and make the discarded branch well-formed).  The answer that quotes cppreference and mentions `dependent_false<T>::value` gives me the information I was looking for, and seems to mean my code is also well-formed.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense @RichardCritten.  It sounds like the template itself is only ill-formed if there exists some code somewhere in it that is ill-formed for every possible instantiation (including code that is always discarded, such as in an `if constexpr (false)` branch).  However, `static_assert(FalseT<T>::value)` could be well-formed if FalseT was specialized later in the program.

Comment: @jcarpenter2 fyi Standard Reference [\[stmt.if #2\]](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.if#2) _"...During the instantiation of an enclosing templated entity ([temp.pre]), if the condition is not value-dependent after its instantiation, the discarded substatement (if any) is not instantiated..."_